# regex pattern c#

Tags: c#, regex, search

I would like to know if anybody can help me. I want to search a string after this pattern x xxx:xxx in file that looks like this:

content of the file

**...
...
customer
1 11:2
material
material data
....
....
  EOF**

The numbers 1, 11, 2 can be any int number like below:
(int number), [space], (int number), [colon], (int number)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivially transforming your requirement to regex, you get:

`(\d+)\s+(\d+)\:(\d+)`